# `.oni` sample/test file resources

Tags: kinect, openni, ofxkinect

Is there any online resources of sample `.oni` files for using as test data for application using the OpenNI framework and other natural interaction devices?

For example, it would be good if there was a resource with one, two, ten people. It seems strange or a shame if there is not, unless developers enjoy dancing in front of their Kinects repeatedly.

I have found [two from the University of Pittsburgh](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~chang/1635/proj11/) and I am currently looking into the OpenNi source/tests.

Comment: Did you find any? (in addition to the University of Pittsburgh files)